# Addends of convex function

Tags: calculus, convex-optimization

If given a function $f(x) = f_{1}(x) + f_2(x) + ... + f_{n}(x)$, and it is known that f(x) is convex. Can I conclude that $f_{i}(x)$ is convex $\forall{i}$?

Comment: Unfortunately not. $f_1(x)=-x^2$, $f_2(x)=x^2$. $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

No.
$$
f(x)=g(x)+(f(x)-g(x))
$$
and you don't have any information on $g$.